# Diferencia entre NgModel y FormControls

Tags: javascript, angular, formularios

soy nuevo en `Angular` y estoy revisando el tema de formulario, especificamente las validaciones. Encontré que existen dos formas de validar formualarios en `Angular`. **FormControls** y **ngModel**. ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre las dos? O ¿Son lo mismo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ngModel**
Permite que desde la vista pueda usar un dato. Y este esté sincronizado con la variable respectiva en JavaScript-TypeScript.
Las modificaciones respectivas en el código *JS* codificara la vista y viceversa.

> Por ejemplo sincronizar un input con tu variable js

**FormControls**
Los forms controls son una especie de variación de los *ngModel* pero especializados para tratar formularios y sus respectivas validaciones. En el puedes crear un objeto y agregar las respectivas reglas de validación de tu formulario.

> Si necesitas crear un formulario tu  mejor alternativa es un **FormControls**.. Por ser este el especializado para estos casos